# Making FollowSymlinks be changed to SymLinksIfOwnerMatch in pre_virtualhost_global.conf

Tags: apache, unix

Been trying to change the /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf to make all instances of "FollowSymLinks" in .htaccess require to be changed to "SymLinksIfOwnerMatch".

```
<Directory "/home">
Options +All +ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

However after using /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf I get the following error;

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 2 of /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf:
```

You may not use 'Options +All' or 'Options -All'.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm sure that should of worked and have no idea why Options +All cannot be used.

I'm using Apache Version: 2.4.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
"Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax..."

But what is not explicitly specified in this documentation is the use of 'All' would seem to logically make the rest of the options redundant. The fact that there is a 'None' option seems to me to indicate that the 'None' option logically replaces a '-All'.